# Apache restart after Access Control update?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

If I add the following Allow restriction to .htaccess, will I need to restart apache for it to take affect?

`Allow from xx.xx.xx.xx`

Comment: No. You would already knew it, if youve tried it out ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You need to restart, only if the rules are added to the config files of Apache.